# Using limit of sinx/x as x approaches 0 to simplify the equation

Tags: calculus, limits

So, I know that I'm supposed to use the rule that the limit of $\sin(x)/x$ as x approaches 0 is equal to 1 to simplify the following:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(4x)}{x+x\cos(5x)} $$

However, I'm not sure where to simplify. Which $x$ on the denominator do I use, and what do I do with the remaining cosines afterwards? According to the review for my test, the final answer is 1/2, but I'm not sure how to reach that after simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor $x$ from $x+x\cos 5x$ then you have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x \cdot \cos 4x}{x(1+\cos 5x)} &= \left(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos 4x}{1+\cos 5x}\right) \\
&= 1\cdot\frac{1}{1+1} = \frac 1 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: I replaced the nicely drawn image of yours by formulas typeset using LaTeX/MathJax, learn about these to write beautiful answers without the need to handwrite formulas.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: As usual, divide both numerator and denominator by $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as $$\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\frac{\cos(4x)}{1+\cos(5x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

1) divide the numerator and the denominator by x.
2) sin(x)/x in numerator will be equal to 1 according to the  sandwitch theorem in limits.
3) then you will remain an equation as   cos(4X)/(1+cos(5x)).
4) direct substitute the x = 0 then you will get the answer as 1/2 .